# How to Create ASP.NET MVC5 Project for VS13

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

When I want to create new project for a website in VS13 I cannot see the ASP.NET MVC 5 I don't know it exactly. If anyone can suggest me what should I use as project ?
My project kind of e-commerce so what will be the best for it to use ?

Thanks for any help.

[I mean it doesn't show like on this img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRwAJ.jpg)

Comment: Did you install it ? https://get.asp.net/  http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5

Comment: I have done only the
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.1.1
It failed after some installation.

By the way I have project created based on MVC4 and while I want to add controller I see MVC 5 but, does it same as create the all project based on MVC 5 or add a controller just ?

Comment: you would need to fix the installation then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual studio 2013 does not have separate project types.

To create MVC5 project, you need to select Framework 4.5 or higher for  ASP.NET Web Application template.

Create project by selecting ASP.NET Web Application

[image]

SELECT MVC Template

[image]

and than check the dll version in bin folder(Or in  references)
[image]

Comment: I already select Framework 4.5 but I see there only ASP.NET MVC 4 there is no MVC 5 so I am just trying to understand the situation.

Comment: So do you mean just select ASP.NET Web Application ?

Comment: I will try after my update just confused cause I see under the topic Visual Studio 2012 as MVC 4 
But now as I understood Web Application is MVC already if I select as you shown above.

Comment: Excellent! It works thank you.